# How to print footer text on every page except the last page in CSS?

Tags: html, css

With this below code, the class `.note` is a footer text that I would like it to be printed on very page except the last page.

```css
@media print {
  body {
    zoom: 85%;
  }
  p.note {
    bottom: -20px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.page-break {
  display: block;
  page-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappeer">
  <p>
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <p>
    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </p>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <p>
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
  </p>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <p>
    <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
  </p>

  <p class="note">In the event that you have doubts or irregularities or both, acts of employees and services Please contact the company by dialing <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;">089 00 89 00</span> or <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;">08900 89 00.</span></p>

</div>
```

Yet, it turned out to print footer text on very page. I have tried some CSS3 of `@page` such as `@page:last{}`, `@page:last-child{}` and `p.note:not(:last){}` to target the last page, but none helps. Without using JS, I prefer any CSS style solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the docs it seems that it's impossible with css only (as for late 2018). It seems that @media print cannot catch the last printing page.

I would solve that like that:

1. Change .note position to absolute and delete it from your code.
2. Change html that the .note p will be placed before every .page-break div.

something like that:

```
<script>
  var pageBreak = document.getElementsByClassName('page-break');
  var note = '<p class="note">In the event that you have doubts or irregularities or both, acts of employees and services Please contact the company by dialing <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;">089 00 89 00</span> or <span style="font-size:14px;font-weight: bold;">08900 89 00.</span></p>';
  for (var i=0; i < pageBreak.length; i++) {
    pageBreak[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', note);
  }
</script>
```

I guess this is the only thing that should be linked for further reading: [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Hope it solve it.

- you should put those h3 out from your p cause it's not valid html, but as for your question it's not related.

---

Old NOT WORKING suggests:
How about hide the last .wrapper .note with css like:

```
.wrapper:last-child .note { display:none; }
```

Edit:

```
.page-break:last-child + p + .note { display: none}
```

Comment: Thanks, the content of `.wrapper` is still there but all class `.note` is gone :(

Comment: @ A.Meshu it does not work as footer text of class `.note` still show up every page. i'm wondering if  pseudo-class `:last-child` works in @media print{} or not. Thanks very much.

Comment: very much thanks for your continuous help, looking forward to hearing from you ;)

Comment: Update my answer. Good luck!

Comment: thanks very much, acknowledge that :last-child won't work in @media print as many of threads out there raise up, would be appreciate for js code to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you have used same content in all pages. But, need to remove the footer text for one page only. So, we can able to hide that footer text in particular page using common javascript code. Please see below code,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    if( getUrl == 'myTest.cfm') {
        $(".note").css("display", "none");
    }
</script>
```

First we need to get the current file name using JS. And then check the filename if condition true means, footer text will be hide.

For example, you have 3 pages means, in the first two pages the footer text will be displayed. But, we don't need footer text for myTest.cfm (last) page. So, using above code, we can able to hide the footer text.

Hope, this will help.

Comment: what is `myTest.cfm` file? I replace with my html file name, yet condition `if( getUrl == 'myTest.cfm')` would never true since `window.location.pathname.split('/')` return an array of file path name each split with `/`. Even though, I tried to make `if-condition` returned true, footer still show up on every pages. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. You can able to replace your html filename. Hope, your file name looks like www.example.com/fileName.html. I have above mentioned code, return the fileName.html only. So, you can able to check easily  with fileName using above mentioned code.

Comment: window.location.pathname.split('/') this code, get the current running file name only.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split('/')` returns an array of element split by `/`, let's say the full path of file is `my/file/name.html` it will return as `['my','file',name.html']`. that's way the comparison of if statement again file name will never true as we compare the array with file name. Anyway, I have made this condition true, it still does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Your filepath will static like as www.example.com/my/file means, we can able to use this code  **var getUrl = window.location.pathname.split('www.example.com/my/file');**. It will work if you have static path for all files.

Comment: `var filename = getUrl[getUrl.length-1]` will returned the file name, I'm not using static url. However, even though `if (filename=='myfile.html')` is true, ` $(".note").css("display", "none");` does not work as expected. Thanks.

Comment: I hope to solve this problem with CSS style rather than using JS.